# Can't compute the Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I tried to calculate an integral with the function `Integrate`, but it runs for a long long time without any answer. I have been checking the integrand and it seems to be fine. And even stranger, sometimes Mathematica could answer and other times it couldn't. Can somebody help me? I have been searching questions of the same type and I found plenty, but I haven't been able to do it.

```
f1[x_, y_, z_] =
 Integrate[
  Cos[a]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(3/
      2), {a, 0, 2*Pi}]

f2[x_, y_, z_] = 
  Integrate[
   Sin[a]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(3/
       2), {a, 0, 2*Pi}];
f3[x_, y_, z_] = 
  Integrate[(r - y*Sin[a] - 
      x*Cos[a])/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 
       2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(3/2), {a, 0, 2*Pi}];
```

And to do the plot i do this

```
VectorPlot3D[{(μ*i*r*z/(4*Pi))*
   N[f1[x, y, z]], (μ*i*r*z/(4*Pi))*
   N[f2[x, y, z]], (μ*i*r/(4*Pi))*N[f3[x, y, z]]}, {x, -0.5, 
  0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, {z, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

The equation corresponds to the magnetic field at a given point created by a spiral (the component x of course).

Comment: Are you okay with a numerical integral? Change it to: `f1[x_, y_, z_, r_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Cos[a]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(3/
      2), {a, 0, 2*Pi}]` which works much better for example: `f1[0.8, 0.5, 1.3, .2]` returns instantly.

Comment: The trapezoidal strategy is a good choice for numerical integration, if you're confident of using only good input values to `f[]`. It should save some time if you have to do a lot of integrals.: `NIntegrate[Cos[a]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(3/2), {a, 0, 2*Pi}, Method -> {"Trapezoidal", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]`

Comment: Actualy i have tried NIntegral and it worked much faster. But i was traying to do a vector plot as well, and because after this i do VectorPlot in a certain range i tried to calculate the generic expression so that the plot then subtituts the variable values. In the polot i put N[f[x,y,z]]

Comment: I tried as well to put the entire expression in the vector plot. Like VectorPlot[{Nintegrate[f[x]]},{x,-1,1}}] (offcourse with the other components), but ii am afried that he will compute the integral i all the interactions.

Comment: @Tomás if you are trying to get a vector plot you need a derivative which is a vector. Your `f1` does not produce a vector but a scalar. You need partial derivatives for each cartesian direction.

Comment: Ya i understand what are you saying, but i am a bit confused.  This is the calculation for a component of the magnetic field. So i´ts a scalar thats is multiplating the unitery vector x. And then i have another 2 expressions for y and z.

Comment: @Tomás put those expressions for the other components in the question, and I will show how to get the vector field.

Comment: i have put them. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use `NIntegrate` and pattern test the arguments to `f1`,`f2`,`f3` with `NumericQ` to ensure `NIntegrate` does not do any symbolic preprocessing first. You do not need `N` as it has no effect here. I've given $\mu$ and $i$ values of 1, but feel free to change them:

```
f1[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Cos[a]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(3/
      2), {a, 0, 2*Pi}];

f2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Sin[a]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(3/
       2), {a, 0, 2*Pi}];

f3[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(r - y*Sin[a] - 
      x*Cos[a])/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 
       2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(3/2), {a, 0, 2*Pi}];

With[{i = 1, μ = 1, r = .1},
 VectorPlot3D[{
   (μ*i*r*z/(4*Pi))*f1[x, y, z, r],
   (μ*i*r*z/(4*Pi))*f2[x, y, z, r],
   (μ*i*r/(4*Pi))*f3[x, y, z, r]
   }, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, {z, -0.5, 0.5}]
 ]
```

[image: magnetic field]

Comment: wow. that was very fast. I can´t thank you enouf.

Answer (score 0):

With Version 12.1.1, at least, the integrals can be obtained symbolically, and I obtained the first one in less than an hour.  Unfortunately, it is an enormous conditional expression.  But, there is an easier way.  Beginning with the expression,

```
fint = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 - 2*r*(x*Cos[a] + y*Sin[a]))^(-1/2);
```

compute

```
f1int = Simplify[(D[fint, x] - x D[fint, z]/z)/r]
(* Cos[a]/(r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 r x Cos[a] - 2 r y Sin[a])^(3/2) *)

f2int = Simplify[(D[fint, y] - y D[fint, z]/z)/r]
(* Sin[a]/(r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 r x Cos[a] - 2 r y Sin[a])^(3/2) *)

f3int = Simplify[-D[fint, r]]
(* (r - x Cos[a] - y Sin[a])/(r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 r x Cos[a] - 2 r y Sin[a])^(3/2) *)
```

The terms `f1int`, `f2int`, and `f3int` are recognizable as the integrands of `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` in the question.  Therefore, the three integrals in the question are simply the corresponding combinations of derivatives of the `fint` integral, which can be obtained in a few minutes.  (The second assumption avoids singularities in `f`.)

```
f = Integrate[f, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, Assumptions -> (x | y | z | r) ∈ Reals && 
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + r^2 + 2 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 0]
(* (4 EllipticK[(4 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/(r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 2 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + z^2)])/
   Sqrt[r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 2 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + z^2] *)
```

For instance, the `f3` integral, obtained in seconds, is

```
FullSimplify[-D[f, r]]
(* (2 (-(-r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2) (r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 2 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + z^2) 
   EllipticE[(4 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/(r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 2 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + z^2)] + 
   ((-r^2 + x^2 + y^2)^2 + 2 (r^2 + x^2 + y^2) z^2 + z^4) EllipticK[(4 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])
   /(r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 2 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + z^2)]))/(r (r^2 + x^2 + y^2 - 2 r 
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + z^2) (r^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 2 r Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + z^2)^(3/2)) *)
```

The `f1` and `f2` integrals are computed similarly from

```
FullSimplify[(D[f, x] - x D[f, z]/z)/r]

FullSimplify[(D[f, y] - y D[f, z]/z)/r]
```

also in seconds.